# Rubber window WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

I create window with set Height and Width. Current content are placed in window. But when I change content rather big then previously it dont placed in window. How create rubber window who automatically change size under the desired?

```html
<Window x:Class="GidroTest.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:gidro_test="clr-namespace:GidroTest"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="200" Width="200"
        WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen"
        >
    <DockPanel>
          <!-- Before click -->
        <Rectangle Width="199" Height="199" Click="Change_size_Click"/>
        <!-- After click -->
        <Rectangle Width="300" Height="300" Click="Change_size_Click"/>
    </DockPanel>        
</Window>
```

Comment: Could you be a bit more specific as to the behavior you want? Perhaps show some screenshots?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try set `SizeToContent` with: `WidthAndHeight`, `Width`, `Height`, don't forget remove `Height`, `Width` from Window

```
<Window SizeToContent="WidthAndHeight">
```

Details: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.window.sizetocontent%28v=vs.110%29.aspx